# Кнопка с выпадающим меню без ссылок

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что за технология используется на сайте для отображения кнопки с выпадающим меню. Есть кнопка выбора объявлений за "Сутки". Никаких ссылок в консоли для этой и подобных кнопок я не вижу. Тогда, как браузер понимает на какую ссылку переходить по нажатию?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылка:

https://am.ru/msk/search/?kladdr%5B0%5D=175849&kladdr%5B1%5D=201046&searchOrder=3&publication=1&photo=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все сделано через JavaScript.
Сделан обычный список ul, внутри элементов li которого вставлены кнопки (button). У них есть атрибут data-target-id, который и задает параметры для отображения объявлений